Django-cte gives: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'with_cte'
I have records in below format:
| id  | name |       created                  |
-----------------------------------------------
|1    | A    |2024-04-10T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|2    | A    |2024-04-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|3    | A    |2024-03-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|4    | A    |2024-02-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|5    | B    |2024-02-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|

Model:
class Model1(model.Models):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

I want to perform a group by in django with month from field created and get latest record from that month.
Expected output:
| id  | name |       created                  |
-----------------------------------------------
|1    | A    |2024-04-10T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|3    | A    |2024-03-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|
|4    | A    |2024-02-01T02:49:47.327583-07:00|

I am using django-cte to perform the above action
from django.db.models.functions import DenseRank, ExtractMonth
from django_cte import With
m = Model1.objects.get(id=1)
cte = With(
        Model1.objects.filter(name=m.name)
          rank=Window(
            expression=DenseRank(),
            partition_by=[ExtractMonth("created")],
            order_by=F("created").desc(),
        )
     )
qs = cte.queryset().with_cte(cte).filter(rank=1)

But the above give error:
qs = cte.queryset().with_cte(cte).filter(rank=1)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'with_cte'

Please help!

You need to mix in the CTEManager, otherwise you get a "vanilla" QuerySet:
from django_cte import CTEManager


class Model1(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = CTEManager()

Thanks for this. I read documentation, but didn't found that we need to also specify this explicitly in model.

You can also explicitly defines the CTEs in the query.
At first annotate each record with the month extracted from the created field and rank them within each month using the DenseRank() function. Then, filter the queryset to get the records with rank 1, which corresponds to the latest record for each month.
Try this:
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import DenseRank, ExtractMonth
from django_cte import With


class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


cte = With(
    Model1.objects.annotate(
        month=ExtractMonth("created"),
        rank=Window(
            expression=DenseRank(),
            partition_by=[ExtractMonth("created")],
            order_by=F("created").desc(),
        ),
    )
)


latest_records = Model1.objects.annotate(
    month=ExtractMonth("created"),
    rank=Window(
        expression=DenseRank(),
        partition_by=[ExtractMonth("created")],
        order_by=F("created").desc(),
    ),
).filter(rank=1)

for record in latest_records:
    print(record.id, record.name, record.created)


this is not working as by default filtering is False: error: django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
